# Telinit: not found

Tags: init, telinit

I have a very simple problem. When trying to launch ubuntu, it gives the error:

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 31 /proc/self/fd/9: telinit: not found
```

I cannot launch ubuntu because of this. Any help or information is appreciated. Thank you! =D

P.S. This comes after a big crash, which resulted in the deletion of `sbin/init`. To fix it, I copied and pasted `sbin/init` from ubuntu live to the real OS. This might be the cause of the problem, idk.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch 14.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall `upstart` using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall upstart
```

As there may be more problems causes by that crash you should consider to do a fresh install of your system.

Comment: TY. I'll try this in about an hour, and mark as correct if that was the solution. =D Cheers

Comment: Ok I tried it and I got an error: `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` So I tried the first recommendation and typed int the -f install. It made the error: `E: Unable to correct dependencies` Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full output?

Comment: And what is apt-get showhold?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I came across the same error today. To solve it

- I boot my ubuntu14.04 using live cd
- copy /sbin/telinit to my harddisk of the same place.
- Then reboot normal

it works.

Comment: As far as I understand the OP already did exactly that and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know if I should accept this answer... I've been using windows for almost a year and a half now!